# Symfony Tow relations berween tow entities

Tags: php, symfony, relationship

I need to create a link between two entities with the following attributes:

First entity (MSG):

- Author (one person)
- Recipients (several ersons)

Nota : The author can be present on the recipients list.

Second entity (Person)

- RecipientOf (list of MSG)
- AuthorOf (list of MSG)

But i don't know how to define the relationship between the two entities.

Can you help me please ?

For your information i'm using SYMFONY2 (Doctrine, PHP, anotations)

Comment: The docs are pretty good and show how you define relationships: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata

Comment: merci pour votre réponse. 
J'ai réuissie à la mettre en place pour 1 seul attribut et pas pour deux

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to determine the relation's type between the two entities :

1. One-to-one
2. Many-to-one
3. Many-to-many

After that, you must map your database tables to specific PHP classes or entities.
I recommend to you the
*[official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/doctrine.html)*.
Otherwise try to look in *[this tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/les-relations-entre-entites-avec-doctrine2)*.